# Generate a readable random unique ID

Tags: php, unique

I need to generate unique transaction IDs. The system allows digits, letters, hyphens, and underscores, but not full stops.

The function I’m currently using is,

```
generate_id() {
    $id = uniqid('P_', true);
    $id = str_replace('.', '-', $id);
    return $id;
}
```

Sample output:

> P_551171d3dd8a93-57457934

However, I have recently found that (a) `uniqid()` isn’t necessarily unique, and (b) my customer occasionally needs to retype these IDs, compare them, search for them, etc. The current IDs are not very readable, and are difficult to eyeball. (I had thought that these were purely for internal use in the payment API. I only recently realised that the customer was actually reading the things.)

So I was thinking of changing to this,

```
function generate_id() {
    $s = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        if ($s) {
            $s .= '-';
        }
        $s .= bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(2));
    }
    return $s;
}
```

Sample output:

> ced7-1cef-5331-193c-907d

`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` is the *recommended* way to generate random unique identifiers, but I fear that doing it four times and concatinating (which I’m doing only because that’s the easiest way to split it up with hyphens for ease of reading) might compromise it. Should I generate one long string and then manipulate it to add hyphens?

Or, indeed, should I do something else altogether? I don’t really mind what the transaction ID looks like, so long as it’s unique and relatively easy to eyeball or retype.

Comment: strictly in math it s imposible random unique ID because random cant be unique. If you want 100% unique Id you need to make auto increment field

Comment: If the customer will be retyping these unique id's, please include a check-digit (or rather 2 like mod97-10). This wil void typo-id's!

Comment: To expand on @Benjamin's Poignt, err, point: there are two approaches to unique ids: centrally managed with an incrementing counter, which guarantees uniqueness; or decentralised with a number long enough generated with a good enough (P)RNG that collisions are *unlikely enough* to matter. If you're using the decentralised random model, calculate your probabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` many times in a row should not be a problem. Whether you read one long string of random bytes or many short strings of random bytes doesn't matter, they're still random. I would still change that code to this, because it's simpler:

```
join('-', str_split(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(40)), 4))
```

This *almost* looks like a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) already, so you may actually want to use one of those instead. While random bytes *should* do, UUIDs are explicitly designed to be globally unique with a high enough probability that you don't need to worry about it in practice at all. Use http://pecl.php.net/package/uuid or your alternative preferred implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a UUID. It can be formed from uniqid() and a custom algorithm or using a library.  If you get a collision using UUID, < insert random massive gift here >.

https://github.com/ramsey/uuid

Comment: Not directly but through a created algorithm which is why using a library or package is easier as we've both mentioned.